# Perl and SNMP - input options

Tags: perl, snmp, net-snmp

script uses [Net::SNMP](http://search.cpan.org/~dtown/Net-SNMP-v6.0.1/lib/Net/SNMP.pm) module for Perl.

I'm trying to run snmpget command with some options added e.g. ( -Ir ) (here is [list](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpcmd.html) of options), but I haven't found any way to do that. In documentation for this module I didn't found anything about adding input options to snmp command.

If there is any other module that supports this, it would bi nice but it wouldn't be first pick as that would require a lot of changes in script (not mine script, just doing minor changes).

I could run system (or backticks) command from Perl, e.g.:

```
snmpget -v2c -c COMMUNITY -Ir HOST OID
```

and parse output but I would like to avoid that also.

Any advice or solution would be welcome since I'm still new to Perl.

Thx.

Comment: You linked to the documentation of Net::SNMP so I'm sure you've read it all before asking. What options do you want to change? There is no "command", there is only your script's calls to the API. `-r` in net-snmp is retries, I think. In Net::SNMP you set the retries flag using the session->retries() function (http://search.cpan.org/~dtown/Net-SNMP-v6.0.1/lib/Net/SNMP.pm#retries%28%29_-_set_or_get_the_current_retry_count_for_the_object) The `-I` flag sets the input format, but you don't need to parse inputs because you are a Perl script, not a command line tool.

Comment: I have red the documentation and I haven't fount solution so I posted for help hare. As stated in question I want to setup -Ir option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You linked to the documentation of Net::SNMP so I'm sure you've read it all before asking... Right?

There is no "command", there is only your script's calls to the API.

[Edit after the below comments]

Net::SNMP has no option to check indexes before sending the request. So, you could say the equivalent of `-Ir` is enabled by default. In fact, Net::SNMP does not load your MIB, so it has no way of checking the validity of your requested variables before sending the request.

Comment: `-Ir` is not the same as `-I -r`, in this case (`snmpget -I -r` fails with `Unknown input option passed to -I: -.`). From `man snmpcmd`: "**-Ir** disables  checking  table  indexes  and  the value to be assigned against the relevant MIB definitions.  This will (hopefully) result in the remote agent reporting an invalid request, rather than checking (and rejecting) this before it is sent to the remote agent."

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want to setup -Ir option, this disables index checking, and it works from command line.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what you want in more detail, I've amended the answer. Whoever voted it down could consider next time to add a better answer if you know an answer is wrong.

Comment: Thx, for your answer. It, wasn't me who voted down. But I'll accept  your answer.